# How do I access to a dynamic HTML element with web scrapping?

Tags: go, web-scraping

I'm using [go-rod](https://github.com/go-rod/rod) for web scrapping. I want to access to a link which is inside a dynamic `<a>`.
To make this `a` visible I have to complete a searcher which is an `input` with the next format (without a `submit`):

```
<form>
    <input> <!--This is the searcher-->
<form/>
```

So, when I complete it, the `a` I want to access appears:
[image: Screenshot of the web]

Until here, all It's ok. This is the code I use to complete the searcher:

```
//Page's url
page := rod.New().MustConnect().MustPage("https://www.sofascore.com/")

//Acept cookies alert
page.MustElement("cookiesAlertSelector...").MustClick()

//Completes the searcher
el := page.MustElement(`searcherSelector...`)
el.MustInput("Lionel Messi")
```

Now the problem appears, when I want to click the `a` which has been displayed after I completed the searcher.

I tried with this:

```
divIWant := page.MustElement("aSelector...")
divIWant.MustClick()
```

and with this:

```
divIWant := page.MustElement("aSelector...").MustWaitVisible()
divIWant.MustClick()
```

But, both of them returns me the same error:

> panic: {-32000 Node is detached from document }
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:
> github.com/go-rod/rod/lib/utils.glob..func2({0x100742dc0?,
> 0x140002bad50?})
> /Users/lucastomicbenitez/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-rod/rod@v0.112.2/lib/utils/utils.go:65
> +0x24 github.com/go-rod/rod.genE.func1({0x14000281ca0?, 0x1003a98b7?, 0x4?})
> /Users/lucastomicbenitez/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-rod/rod@v0.112.2/must.go:36
> +0x64 github.com/go-rod/rod.(*Element).MustClick(0x14000289320)   /Users/lucastomicbenitez/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-rod/rod@v0.112.2/must.go:729
> +0x9c main.main()     /Users/lucastomicbenitez/development/golang/evolutionaryAlgorithm/main/main.go:22
> +0x9c exit status 2

So, looking for some solution I found [this github issue](https://github.com/go-rod/rod/issues/170) and tried this to get the link:

```
link := page.MustEval(`()=> document.querySelector('aSelector...').href`)
```

But it returns this:

> panic: eval js error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'href')

However, I'm pretty sure the selector is correct.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may just need to wait some time between entering the search key and reading the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Hymns For Disco said in the comments, I just needed to wait some time after the searcher is completed.

```
el.MustInput("Lionel Messi")

time.Sleep(time.Second)

link := page.MustEval(`()=> document.querySelector('aSelector...').href`)
```